# How to convert Json to Java object using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Suppose I have json string

```
{"userId":"1","userName":"Yasir"}
```

now I have a class User

```
class User{
int userId;
String userName;
//setters and getters
}
```

Now How can I convert above json string to user class object

Comment: User user=new Gson().fromJson(yourJsonString,User.class);

Comment: As an FYI to anyone starting out with just JSON - from an API they're consuming say: There are a lot of services - utilities and online - which can take the JSON and generate the corresponding class or nested classes automatically. for example http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/ . So you can just drop those POJOS into your project and still use the top answer. saves time and typos.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonInString = "{\"userId\":\"1\",\"userName\":\"Yasir\"}";
User user= gson.fromJson(jsonInString, User.class);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
User user= gson.fromJson(jsonInString, User.class);

// where jsonInString is your json {"userId":"1","userName":"Yasir"}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
User user = gson.fromJson("{\"userId\":\"1\",\"userName\":\"Yasir\"}", User.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

User u=gson.fromJson(jsonstring, User.class);
System.out.println("userName: "+u.getusername);
```