# Spring Elasticsearch JSON to Object for Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, elasticsearch, thymeleaf

When I get results by query of Elasticsearch on Thymeleaf HTML, it shows as JSON, not as object like `findAll` or `findbyID`. I want to get as object then I can get values to table like `user.firstname`, `user.lastname` of `elements` children of JSON like looking of index. How can I do this with GSON (JSON to object) or other way?

find all (index page)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66vao.png)

query search result: /searchresults/asd
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhRyU.png)

```
<tr th:each="food : ${query}">
<td th:text="${food.elements}">
<!--<td th:text="${food.id}"></td>
<td th:text="${food.firstName}"></td>
<td th:text="${food.lastName}"></td>
<td th:text="${movie.imglink}"></td>-->
```

Original JSON by my REST API: /search/query/test

```
{"timeTook":0.005,"numberOfResults":2,"elements":"[{\"highlight\":{\"lastName\":[\"<em>Asdfasd<\\/em>\"]},\"_index\":\"user\",\"_type\":\"_doc\",\"_source\":{\"firstName\":\"Test\",\"lastName\":\"Asdfasd\",\"modificationDate\":1595572482000,\"_class\":\"com.example.springmysqlelastic.model.UserModel\",\"id\":1},\"_id\":\"1\",\"sort\":[1],\"_score\":null},{\"highlight\":{\"lastName\":[\"<em>sadasd<\\/em>\"]},\"_index\":\"user\",\"_type\":\"_doc\",\"_source\":{\"firstName\":\"asfas\",\"lastName\":\"sadasd\",\"modificationDate\":1595572482000,\"_class\":\"com.example.springmysqlelastic.model.UserModel\",\"id\":2},\"_id\":\"2\",\"sort\":[2],\"_score\":null}]"}
```

Searchnormalcontroller.java

```
@Controller
public class SearchNormalController {
    
    private final ISearchService searchService;
        
    @Autowired
    public SearchNormalController(ISearchService searchService) {
        this.searchService = searchService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/searchresults/{query}") //value = {"/searchresults", "/"}
    public String  searchResultsFoods(@PathVariable String query, Model model) throws IOException {
        model.addAttribute("query", searchService.searchFromQuery(query.trim().toLowerCase()));
        return "searchresults";
    }
}
```

searchservice.java

```
@Service
public class SearchService implements ISearchService {
    
    //private ESConfig esco;

    @Value("${api.elasticsearch.uri}")
    private String elasticSearchUri;

    @Value("${api.elasticsearch.search}")
    private String elasticSearchSearchPrefix;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SearchService.class);

    @Override
    public ResultQuery searchFromQuery(String query) throws IOException {
        String body = HelperFunctions.buildMultiIndexMatchBody(query);
        return executeHttpRequest(body);
    }

    /**
     * Fetch resultQuery from elastic engine for the given body
     *
     * @param body String
     * @return ResultQuery
     * @throws IOException IOException
     */
    private ResultQuery executeHttpRequest(String body) throws IOException{
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            ResultQuery resultQuery = new ResultQuery();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(HelperFunctions.buildSearchUri(elasticSearchUri
                    , "", elasticSearchSearchPrefix));
            httpPost.setHeader(Constants.CONTENT_ACCEPT, Constants.APP_TYPE);
            httpPost.setHeader(Constants.CONTENT_TYPE, Constants.APP_TYPE);
            
            //esco.elasticsearchClient();
            byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64("elastic:666666".getBytes());

            String ELASTICUSER_PASS = new String(encodedBytes);
            httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + ELASTICUSER_PASS);
            //httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic ZWxhc3RpYzo2NjY2NjY=");
            
            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(body, Constants.ENCODING_UTF8));
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                String message = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(message);
                if(myObject.getJSONObject(Constants.HITS).getJSONObject("total")
                        .getInt("value") != 0){
                    resultQuery
                            .setElements(myObject
                                    .getJSONObject(Constants.HITS)
                                    .getJSONArray(Constants.HITS)
                                    .toString());
                    resultQuery
                            .setNumberOfResults(myObject.getJSONObject(Constants.HITS).getJSONObject("total")
                                    .getInt("value"));
                    resultQuery.setTimeTook((float) ((double) myObject.getInt(Constants.TOOK) / Constants.TO_MS));
                } else {
                    resultQuery.setElements(null);
                    resultQuery.setNumberOfResults(0);
                    resultQuery.setTimeTook((float) ((double) myObject.getInt(Constants.TOOK) / Constants.TO_MS));
                }
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error while connecting to elastic engine --> {}", e.getMessage());
                resultQuery.setNumberOfResults(0);
            }

            return resultQuery;
        }
    }
}
```

resultquery.java

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ResultQuery {

    private Float timeTook; //ElasticSearch response time in seconds
    private Integer numberOfResults; //the number of total elements retrieved
    private String elements; //a stringified JSON that represents the total hits found.

}
```

Comment: The JSON string in your question is not valid JSON (even allowing for the Java string escaping of double quotes: `\"`). For example: `"elements":"[{...`. Overall, it looks like a valid JSON response from Elasticsearch, with some invalid extra items added to the start.

Comment: You need the SearchResult as an Object in ResultQuery not as String elements.

Comment: _I want to get as object of JSON How can i do this with GSON_ - There are various questions and answers covering that - for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377754/parse-json-file-using-gson) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636254/how-to-convert-json-to-java-object-using-gson). There are also tutorials, for example, [here](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-parse-json-with-gson/) and [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson.html). Those should all help you.